# Geonode OAuth2 error when edit style

Tags: geoserver, geonode

I installed geonode following this instructions: http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/ In the end it say that if you log-in in geonode then geoserver is also authenticated, but in my case that did not happend. So I follow this instructions to configure the OAuth2 http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/geoserver_geonode_security/index.html and the test conection worked well. The thing is that when I try to update the style of a layer I get the error: "There was an error saving the style back to the server".

**Apache logs says:**

> [wsgi:error] [pid 6886:tid 140619259516672] Internal Server Error:
>   /gs/rest/styles/line.xml
>
> ....
>
> [wsgi:error] [pid 6886:tid 140619259516672]   File
>   "/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/geoserver/signals.py", line 133, in
>   geoserver_pre_save [wsgi:error] [pid 6886:tid 140619259516672]
>   'type': None} [wsgi:error] [pid 6886:tid 140619259516672]
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attribution'

**Geoserver logs says:**

*(When sudo service tomcat8 restart)*

> INFO [geoserver.global] - Falling back to embedded data directory:
>   /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/data
>
> WARN [geoserver.config] - Error reading resource URL
>   [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties]
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL
>   [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties]
>   cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in
>   the file system:
>   jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties
>
> ....

(When update the style)

> ERROR [geoserver.security] - Could not Authorize OAuth2 Resource due
>   to the following exception:
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for
>   "http://localhost:8000/api/o/v4/tokeninfo/?access_token=gFq6vD2g21eNMAQ9HILSsNEwqXo8Gb":
>   Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>
> ....

Could you give some recommendations, what things should I check?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure tomcat has write access to geoserver_data directory.

```
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/data
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/data
```